# How to pass an int between activities?

Tags: android

I'm making an Android quiz and one activity stores every question. Now the score displays on that activity and I would like it if it that score goes to a new activity.. and displays..

code in the quiz:

```
Intent theIntent = new Intent(this, Score.class);
            theIntent.putExtra("somename", score);  
            startActivity(theIntent);
```

code in the score:

```
int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("somename");
```

I get an error on this word.. "getIntExtra" above in the score activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getIntExtra() takes a second parameter (default value in case the extra can't be found):

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("somename", 0);
```

would do the job

Comment: I've put this code to try to pass an score to a second activity but the application crashes when I reach the end of the quiz...

Comment: If the app crashes then certainly not because of the code above. Create a new question for that crash as it's definitely unrelated to this question. And post the stack trace. Without that most crash related questions can't be answered.

Comment: Yea, it was because I declared a button and didn't put "setContentView" in the score activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must provide a default value in the case that the integer doesn't exist in the intent extras.

[Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

> public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)
>   Retrieve extended data from the intent.
>
> Parameters:
>
> name: The name of the desired item.
>
> defaultValue: the value to be returned if no value of the desired type is stored with the given name.
>
> Returns
>   the value of an item that previously added with putExtra() or the default value if none was found.